# Why won't React component re-render after setting new state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that doesn't appear to re-render even though the parent state has in fact updated.

Here is the (contrived) code:

```
const Index = () => {
    render (
        <Foo initialFoo={{ isTrue: true, count: 0 }} />
    )
}

const Foo = ({ initialFoo }) => {
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState({ ...initialFoo })

    const reset = () => {
        setFoo({ ...initialFoo })
    }

    return (
        <>
        {
            foo.isTrue ?
            <Bar initialBar={foo} reset={reset} /> :
            <span>{foo.count}</span>
        }
        </>
    )
}

const Bar = ({ initialBar, reset }) => {
    const [bar, setBar] = useState({ ...initialBar })

    return (
        <div
            onMouseOver={() => setBar({ ...bar, count: bar.count + 1 })}
            onClick={reset}
        >
            <span>{bar.count}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hovering over the component increments `count` by 1 and displays it accordingly, but when I click on it, nothing changes when I expect the initial state to be displayed.

If I add logs in the `Foo` component, I can see that `foo` is updating back to the initial state after clicking on the component, but `Bar` isn't re-rendering even though it depends on `foo`. Shouldn't a change in state in the parent component trigger the children to re-render?

Note: I'm not looking for suggestions on how to write the code better/differently to achieve the desired result, rather just trying to understand the reason why the component is not displaying the original state after clicking on it in this current setup

Comment: Interesting question. I'm relatively new to react and especially hooks. I'm not sure why you see this behavior. I suggest using the React Dev Tools to see if there are any clues there as to what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare this state:

```
const [bar, setBar] = useState({ ...initialBar })
```

You are telling React to start tracking a new state variable which is initialised with the current value of `initialBar`. When the value of `initialBar` changes in future renders, it will have no effect on the state derived from it - the initialisation only happens on component mount.

To keep `bar` synchronised with `initialBar`, you would need to add a `useEffect` and manually set `bar` yourself:

```
const [bar, setBar] = useState({ ...initialBar })

useEffect(() => {
  setBar(initialBar)
}, [initialBar])
```

This effect will be run only when the reference value of `initialBar` changes, which is currently only when the `reset` function is called. You would also effectively be setting `bar` twice on component mount.

Comment: But when `foo` is updated, shouldn't that automatically re-mount the `Bar` component with the "new" `foo` given that one of its props have been updated?

Comment: @ezrag26 It's not re-mounted. It's re-rendered. But the updated props doesn't have an impact on the state of `Bar`, so nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected, `reset` drops `foo` to initail state but in you Bar component initialBar is used only to populate the initial state and it will not update after that.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return <Index />;
}

const Index = () => {
  return <Foo initialFoo={{ isTrue: true, count: 0 }} />;
};

const Foo = ({ initialFoo }) => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState({ ...initialFoo });

  const reset = () => {
    console.log(foo, initialFoo);
    setFoo({ ...initialFoo });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {foo.isTrue ? (
        <Bar initialBar={foo} reset={reset} />
      ) : (
        <span>{foo.count}</span>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const Bar = ({ initialBar, reset }) => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState({ ...initialBar });

  // Uncomment to update bar on initialBar changed
  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    setBar({ ...initialBar });
  }, [initialBar]);
  */

  return (
    <button
      onMouseOver={() => setBar({ ...bar, count: bar.count + 1 })}
      onClick={reset}
    >
      <span>{bar.count}</span>
    </button>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit compassionate-bohr-8ehbkd]